# how do i make a button in a different view, send an action to something located in the other view?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I have a utility application (the flippy template) and i would like to make a button on the flipside view, trigger an IBAction in the main view. how do i do this?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with delegates.

If your flipside view has a delegate (and for 99% it has), you can do something like this in `FlipsideViewController.m`:

```
- (void)buttonClicked:(id)sender {
     [[self delegate] flipsideButtonClicked];
}
```

In `NormalViewController.m` insert:

```
- (void)flipsideButtonClicked {
    // do your stuff
}
```

In `NormalViewController.h`:

```
@interface ... {
    ...
}

// add this:
- (void)flipsideButtonClicked;
```